# Finding value of a constant from a point

Tags: geometry

I have the question "The point $M(K,2K)$ lies on the line with equation $X -3Y + 15 = 0$.

Find the value of the constant $K$."

I'm unsure of how to start this off. Could you please explain the steps needed so i can solve this myself.

Answer (score 3):

You know that $x=k$ and $y=2k$. Plug these values into $x-3y+15=0$ and solve for $k$.

Comment: So would the answer be k = 3 ?

Comment: Sounds correct!

Comment: Thank you. I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

solve the equation $$K-3\cdot (2K)+15=0$$ for $K$